# Conditions on belongs_to

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model, associations

I have this model called `Request`, which `belongs_to` a `User`.

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to :user, :conditions => "can_make_requests = t"
end
```

The `User` model has a boolean field in its schema named `can_make_requests`, but for some reason, when I try

```
aUser.requests.create
```

when `aUser` has `can_make_requests` as `f`, it still works (`aUser.requests.first` returns the newly made request). Does anyone know what the issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `User#requests` association, which has no clue about your conditions on `Request#user`.

`aUser.requests.create` builds and saves a `Request` object based on any conditions given on the `requests` association and adds it to the list of associated requests.

Sure, `Request` happens to have a `user` association, but that is never used in your examples.

And yes, it leads to weird behavior and inconsistencies:

```
>> user = User.create(:can_make_requests => false)
=> #<User id: 3, can_make_requests: false>
>> request = user.requests.create
=> #<Request id: 2, user_id: 3>
>> request.user
=> nil
>> user.requests
=> [#<Request id: 2, user_id: 3]
```

If you want to enforce it from the Request level using validations, you can do something like:

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :user, :presence => true
  validate :user_can_make_requests

  def user_can_make_requests
    errors[:user] << 'cannot make requests' if user && !user.can_make_requests?
  end
end
```

Comment: Is there way to enforce this by using validations then? Force it so that when the Request is saved, it has to have a `user_id`, and the `User` referenced by the `user_id` has to have `:can_make_requests => true`?

Comment: Updated my answer with a way to do this

Answer (score 1):

For PostgreSQL (and SQLite under Rails), you'd want `'t'` for true, not just `t`. Of course, for MySQL, you'd want `1`. Try changing your `:conditions` to this:

```
belongs_to :user, :conditions => [ 'can_make_requests = ?', true ]
```

Or:

```
belongs_to :user, :conditions => { :can_make_requests => true }
```

That should get you the appropriate true value for whatever database you're using.